# Is there an antonym for "nonstick"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, retronyms

I have a pan that is not a nonstick pan. Is there a word to describe it? Something less awkward than "non-nonstick"? Maybe "stick" or "sticky", but I've never heard those words used in that sense. Maybe "conventional", but that word is vague.

I looked on Google but couldn't find anything that looked reasonable.

Comment: Are you looking for a term for pans in particular?  *regular*?   “I have 2 regular skillets and 1 non-stick”

Comment: Yeah, there's a term, but it's tacky.

Comment: By "nonstick" do you mean "Teflon-coated"? The terms are only sometimes used as synonyms.

Comment: How (and under what circumstances) would you use this in a sentence? I don't think there is an antonym, nor can I really imagine the need for one.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - If there were a word you could say, “Only use a <word> skillet when searing food; a nonstick skillet just will not produce a good sear.”   Of course in that context “regular” or “traditional” or “stainless” would work.

Comment: A pan was just a pan until non-stick ones were invented (which I'm old enough to remember). You could say "Don't use a non-stick one" or similar.

Comment: *PTFE-free*? *Stainless steel*? *Metal*? *Steel or copper*? (Note that non-stick cookware is normally made of aluminum while non-non-stick is normally steel, iron, or maybe copper.) There's no particularly good antonym, but lots of phrases that will work in context.

Comment: I've found << Tower Piece 5 Aluminium Not non-stick Cookware set >> on the internet, but I'll not put it forward as a fixed phrase. Useable, though.

Comment: @Jim : But there's not any one word. One would say: “Never use a nonstick skillet when searing food; a nonstick skillet just will not produce a good sear.” Not: “Only use a traditional, regular, stainless steel, copper, or cast iron skillet when searing food; a nonstick skillet just will not produce a good sear.” There *is* a cooking stackexchange where one might further inquire: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TinfoilHat - I was suggesting to choose *one*. Personally I’d go for traditional.  Edit actually I think in OP’s case use traditional plus the actual type trash it is:  “I have a traditional stainless steel pan...”

Comment: Wow.  My phone changed “pan” to “trash”!!?  WTF!

Comment: @HotLicks should get a bounty for that comment.

Answer (score 3):

Pans made of different materials have, of course, different degrees of stickiness. So one would typically just state the pan's material, e.g. "a stainless steel pan" or "a cast-iron pan." There isn't a single umbrella term for all pans without a nonstick coating, since such pans do not necessarily share similar "sticking" behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen "non-coated" but it isn't very commonly used, so make sure the context makes your meaning clear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The problem is, there are plenty of pans that are coated, but not non-stick.  Enamelled cast iron is one significant example.  Some of the ceramic hard coatings may be called non-stick, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard term.

As non-stick (or sometimes nonstick) usually refers to pans with a Teflon (PTFE) coating, I might use **non-teflon** if I wanted to refer to a pan that could be used at high heat dry, or with metal utensils.  *Non-teflon* would permit the harder and less effective ceramic non-stick coatings, which you might or might not want - the example of searing suggests that they'd by fine.

I have also used **non-non-stick** in my own notes and [in a post a cooking.se](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/116095/20413).  That doesn't mean I like or recommend it, just that I couldn't come up with anything better.

Otherwise I've constructed the sentence differently

> *In a heavy pan (not non-stick) you need very little oil*

and

> *I wouldn't use non stick for this because a dry pan can get very hot in places*

are two more examples from my posts at cooking.se